# OpenGL glsl shader version error

Tags: opengl, glsl, video-card

I'm learning GLSL to do some computer graphics experiment now. While I tried to compile shaders from some tutorials, I ran into some problems. Here it was:
GL version: 3.0.0 - Build 8.15.10.2291
Error compiling shader type 35633: 'ERROR: 0:1: '' :  Version number not support
ed by OGL driver
The video card of my laptop is GT520M, but I've already updated my video card driver to the version340.82,which is said to support OpenGL 4.5 and GLSL 4.50.

Comment: So which version did you specify? What happens if you try to compile your shader without specifying a version?

Comment: Since my OpenGL version is 3.0.0, the glsl version is 1.30. In the vertex shader,the key word 'layout' produce a error ,which belongs to a higher glsl version.

Comment: Please post the exact version line you have in your shader. You know, that glsl versions are given without the .? so it should be #version 130 in your case.

Comment: Sorry ,my mistake.  This what i got using glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) **GLSL version: 1.30  - Intel Build 8.15.10.2291**,the verison line in shader is **#version 330**.But what i am puzzled is why the OpenGL version is not updated to 4.5 after I updated the video card driver to 340.82

Comment: That would be because you are using your laptop's integrated graphics (Intel HD), instead of the dedicated card (GT 520M).

Comment: To add to Sir.Tiddlesworth's comment, with an Optimus laptop (on Windows) you can choose which GPU to use by default on a global scale or per application via the NVIDIA system settings or context menu when clicking on a link to an application or the executable itself. Optimus laptops pose or posed a problem for some people, especially Linux users like me, but are also an opportunity as you got GPU from two vendors and different sets of supported GL functionality at hand for development and testing.

Comment: Thank you all . Problem was solved after setting the NVIDIA card as default on a global scale. I thought the system would switch between two card automatically before...